# ASP.NET C# - Refresh 2nd DropdownList based on select of 1st dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET

I have this code Page1.aspx for the DetailsView:

```
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList id="VendorName" datasourceid="VendorSqlDataSource"
                        datatextfield="VendorName" DataValueField="VendorID"  
                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("VendorID") %>' runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList id="VendorName" datasourceid="VendorSqlDataSource"
                    datatextfield="VendorName"  DataValueField="VendorID"  
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("VendorID") %>'   runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="dllVendor_OnSelectedIndexChanged"  AutoPostBack="true" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vendor BU">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="VendorBUName" runat="Server" style="text-align:left; width:100%" Text='<%# Eval("VendorBUName")%>' Width="70%"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList id="VendorBUName" datasourceid="VendorBUSqlDataSource"
                        datatextfield="VendorBUName" DataValueField="VendorBUID"  
                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("VendorBUID") %>' runat="server"/>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList id="VendorBUName" datasourceid="VendorBUSqlDataSource"
                    datatextfield="VendorBUName"    DataValueField="VendorBUID"  
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("VendorBUID") %>'   runat="server"/>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

I am trying to make the code behind Page1.aspx.cs to refresh the 2nd Dropdown List in this code behind:

```
(VendorBUName"), but keeps getting a error "".
    protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object VendorID)
    {
        string queryString = "SELECT VendorBUID, VendorBUName From MDF_VendorBU WHERE VendorID = @VendorID";
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VendorID", VendorID);
        connection.Open();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        ad.Fill(dt);

        /*
        VendorBUName.Items.Clear();
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            VendorBUName.DataSource = dt;
            VendorBUName.DataTextField = "VendorBUName";
            VendorBUName.DataValueField = "VendorBUID";
            VendorBUName.DataBind();
        }
        */

        connection.Close(); 


    }

    //protected void dllVendor_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    //{ 
        //OnSelectedIndexChanged(VendorName.SelectedValue.ToString());
    //}
```

I am keep getting the "The name 'VendorBUName' does not exist in the current context", looks like code behind is not recognize the 2nd dropdownlist in the Page1.aspx

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use a FindControl call here since you have a label AND a combo box both with the same name.
So in OnSelectedIndexChanged do something like

```
var control = (DropDownList) yourDetailsView.FindControl("VendorBUName");
if(control!=null)
{
   //do your stuff on the drop down
}
```

Comment: I tried, but didn't work. Can you help modify my codes I posted?